# Unable to decode mxGraph cell data from xml to object using mxObjectDecode

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml, mxgraph

I am using mxGraph JS library in my project to construct graphs. 
I am able to construct graph, encode it to xml and decode the xml to graph.

**Problem**

I have a custom class `Message`, whose object I set into `cell.data` for the corresponding `mxCell` returned after calling `graph.insertVertex()` function.

The `Message` class looks like this:

```
class Message {
    constructor(title) {
        this.attributes = {};
        this.attributes.title = title;
        this.attributes.audioPath = "";
    }
```

There's another class called `Type` to enclose the `Message` object. Its just the demand of the logic. Looks like this:

```
class Type{
  constructor(a,b){
    this.object = a;
    this.type = b;
  }
}
```

I insert the vertex in graph and set cell data like this:

```
Message m=new Message(); //new Message object
m.attributes.title="Sample"; //setting message attributes

cell = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, this.attributes.title, 20, 40, 80, 30); //inserting vertex in graph

Type type=new Type(); //new Type object
type.type="msg"; 
type.object=m;

cell.data=m; //Setting type to cell data
```

Now I register my `Message` object in `mxCodecRegistry`:

```
var messageCodec = new mxObjectCodec(new Message());
messageCodec.encode = function(enc, obj) {
    var node = enc.document.createElement('message');
    mxUtils.setTextContent(node, JSON.stringify(obj.attributes));
    return node;
};
messageCodec.decode = function(dec, node, into) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(mxUtils.getTextContent(node));
    obj.constructor = Message;

    return obj;
};

mxCodecRegistry.register(messageCodec);
```

After this I encode my graph to xml. Here's the code and output xml:

**CODE:**

```
var encoder  = new mxCodec();
var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
xml = mxUtils.getXml(node);

//mxUtils.popup(xml, true);
return xml;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mxGraphModel>
   <root>
      <mxCell id="0" />
      <mxCell id="1" parent="0" />
      <mxCell id="8" value="Sample" vertex="1" parent="1">
         <mxGeometry x="338.5" y="180" width="40" height="20" as="geometry" />
         <Type type="msg" as="data">
            <message as="object">{"title":"Insert_1"}</message>
         </Type>
      </mxCell>
   </root>
</mxGraphModel>
```

Decoding xml to graph and printing `cell.data` in console:

**CODE:**

```
var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
var codec = new mxCodec(doc);
codec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
for(var i in graph2.getChildCells() ) {
        console.log("cell" + i + ":" + JSON.stringify(graph.getChildCells()[i].data));
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
cell0:{}
cell1:{}
```

Please help me. I want the cell data to convert back to the object so that I can access all attributes directly.